# Proper representation of "vice versa"?

Tags: adverbs

How should I properly use the word *vice versa* in writing?  Is that even the correct spelling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Vice versa" is surely correct, see e.g. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vice+versa). Wiktionary [suggests](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vice_vers%C3%A2) that you could write "vice versâ" if you wanted to expressly mark the ablative case, and they even provide a quote, but that is actually the first time I see that spelling in an English context (we don't have the ablative case, after all).

If you don't like the expression itself for some reason, you can go with the English equivalent "the other way round".

Comment: Well, I have to say, it looks like Wiktionary demonstrates that you could write "vice versâ" as recently as 170 years ago :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Yep, and I will add that even if it had been the prevalent spelling as recently as 20 years ago, by now it would have lost to "vice versa" anyway. (Everybody can find the letter "a" on their keyboard, but few people know how to type an "â", and barely anyone can be bothered actually doing it.)

Comment: Yeah â is a tough one... it's a letter in Romanian, but even on Romanian signs in Romania they use á or ã because it's easier..